# Nest queries with field priority and filter query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying build a search functionality with ElasticSearch using Nest. What I need is following:

- I have product table and I indexed is as below:

  ```
  foreach (var product in products) {
      Product product = new Product(product.ProductId, product.Name, product.Number, product.Description);   
      ElasticClient.Index(productes);
  }
  ```
- Then I execute following queries:

  1. This works fine. I get results.

     ```
     var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(body => body.Query(query => query.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(key))).Size(20));
     ```

     Both none of the below queries work. Why? What am I doing wrong?
  2. -

     ```
     var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(body => body.Filter(filter => filter.Term(x => x.Name, key)).Take(1000));
     ```
  3. -

     ```
     var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(s => s
         .From(0)
         .Size(15)
         .Query(q => q
             .Term(p => p.Name, key)));
     ```
  4. -

     ```
     var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(body => body.Query(query => query.ConstantScore(csq => csq.Filter(filter => filter.Term(x => x.Name, key.ToLower())))).Take(1000));
     ```

I would like to first of all understand why queries with filter don't work for me. Finally, I want to achieve a query that searches a given keyword and prioritizes results based on which field (column, property) it was found in.

So if keyword was in the "name" field, it should be returned at the top. So respectively, "Name", "Number", "Description". How can I achieve such a query?

EDIT: I tried the query below but it doesn't return anything.

```
var results = ElasticClient.Search<Product>(body => body
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                .Add(entry => entry.Name, 5.0)
                .Add(entry => entry.Number, 3.0)
                .Add(entry => entry.Description, 2.0))
            .Query(key))));
```

Below some samples data;
when I send "2000" as keyword, I get following results with 1. query but others will not return anything.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share some sample documents with sample values of "Name" field?

Comment: @bittusarkar I added some sample values, Is that sufficient?

Comment: In your queries above, what do you use for the `key` variable? Can you share what keywords you're searching on?

Comment: @Val as i have written there, I use "2000" as keyword and results are returned for the first query but not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why the first query returns results and the others don't is because the first query is a `query_string` and the input keyword (e.g. `2000`) will be analyzed and matched with any of your fields (which are also analyzed). This is not the case of the second, third and fourth queries because you're using a `term` query/filter where the input is not analyzed and instead matched **as is**.

If we take the first document (id=13), the `name` field will be analyzed and indexed as the following tokens: `dr`, `2000`, `12k` (in lowercase!) as can be seen with the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&analyzer=standard' -d 'DR-2000 (12k)'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "dr",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "2000",
    "start_offset" : 3,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "12k",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```

So when searching for `2000` (or `dr` or `12k`) in a `query_string` query, you'll find that document. Searching for the term `2000` won't yield anything though, which is expected when using `term` query/filter that work for exact matching.

As for your second question on boosting fields, the reason that query returns nothing is maybe because the field names [are lowercased by default](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1273) (default behavior of NEST). You should make sure to use lowercase field names.

**UPDATE**

If you need to perform exact matching, I advise to change your field mappings to [multi-field string fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) with an `analyzed` and a `not_analyzed` field.

```
{
  "product" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "analyzed",
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query the `name` field with `query_string` when you need **like** behavior and the `name.raw` field when you need exact match behavior with `term` query/filter.

Comment: I am actually using this line          settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p);      It doesnt help for the lowercase situation. I read that if i use this setting, it should interprete as it is, not with lowercase.

Comment: Ok, did you get the info you expected for your first answer, though?

Comment: So basically,term filter is an exact match, just like in sql = equal clause while query string is like a "like %key%" where clause if put this in sql terms. is that what you are saying?

Comment: But i am trying to execute 2nd query by giving exact word as DR-2000(12k) for example and it didnt work. I even changed this from Name to Number field to be searched and I gave 10002 which is the number for Id=13. still not returned.

Comment: That's because your fields are all analyzed (and thus tokenized) and the exact value you have input is not indexed as is. For that you'd need a `not_analyzed` field. I will update my answer to include this.

Comment: perfect. thank you very much. one last question. Do I have to reindex everything or is there any update query with Nest?

Comment: Yes, you do have to reindex your data, and/or update all your documents, which is the same thing.